# Conditional word frequency count in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe like below:

```
data = {'speaker':['Adam','Ben','Clair'],
        'speech': ['Thank you very much and good afternoon.',
                   'Let me clarify that because I want to make sure we have got everything right',
                   'By now you should have some good rest']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to count the number of words in the speech column but only for the words from a pre-defined list. For example, the list is:

```
wordlist = ['much', 'good','right']
```

I want to generate a new column which shows the frequency of these three words in each row. My expected output is therefore:

```
     speaker                   speech                               words
0   Adam          Thank you very much and good afternoon.             2
1   Ben        Let me clarify that because I want to make sur...      1
2   Clair        By now you should have received a copy of our ...    1
```

I tried:

```
df['total'] = 0
for word in df['speech'].str.split():
    if word in wordlist: 
        df['total'] += 1
```

But I after running it, the `total` column is always zero. I am wondering what's wrong with my code?

Comment: To understand what's the problem with your code, you can start by printing each word inside the loop. You will see you word is actually a list of strings, not a string. In addition, when you do df['total'] += 1, you add 1 to each element of column df.total, and this is not what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AnnaK.Thanks for the explanation. I do see now that word is a list of words, not individual words (but I am puzzled by why jupytyer does not show an error when running "if word in wordlist"). I am wondering if I want to write it correctly (that is, word is individual words), how should I write it?

Comment: I like the answer of @CDBJ. You should avoid loops over rows of dataframes whenever possible.

Comment: I understand what you mean and would definitely keep that in mind in the future. But just out of curiosity, how could I get the individual words for each row if the `string.split` does not work? I have been searching for it, but have not found a good answer...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following vectorised approach:

```
data = {'speaker':['Adam','Ben','Clair'],
        'speech': ['Thank you very much and good afternoon.',
                   'Let me clarify that because I want to make sure we have got everything right',
                   'By now you should have some good rest']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

wordlist = ['much', 'good','right']

df['total'] = df['speech'].str.count(r'\b|\b'.join(wordlist))
```

Which gives:

```
>>> df
  speaker                                             speech  total
0    Adam            Thank you very much and good afternoon.      2
1     Ben  Let me clarify that because I want to make sur...      1
2   Clair              By now you should have some good rest      1
```

Comment: many thanks for the solution! I just looked `series.str.count` up and ran your code on a test sample. It worked well! But I am wondering could you help me to understand it better? I have two questions, 1) what is the function of | in the brackets (to separate the words in the wordlist?) and 2) how to use `.join`? I apologize if they are silly questions, but I have spent the past hour trying to understand them by myself, but still have no clue...

Comment: now I understand! Such a neat and useful combination. Thank you very much! But may I ask another question? In @Anna K. comment, it is said "You should avoid loops over rows of dataframes whenever possible". I can see that there is no explicit loop in `string.count()`, but how does it work? Does it start with the `wordlist` and count the occurance of each word in each row, and then sum them up? (as opposed my failed method, where I started by looking at each individual words in each row and check whether it's included in the `wordlist` and then sum all the matched words).

Comment: Really sorry to bother again. But I just found a bug with the `str.count('|'.join(wordlist))` method. To give an example, if the `speech` is "afternoon", the count (`total`) will be 1 when the `wordlist` is "afternoon" or "no" or "after" (if the `wordlist` include both "no" and "afternoon", the count is still 1. When the `wordlist` include all "no","afternoon", and "after", the count is also 1. But when the three words are included in a very big wordlist, the count becomes 3). I tried the whole morning to understand it, but really could not...Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I finally figured it out. I think it has someting to do with using `|` to delimit the `wordlist`. If I change the code to `str.count(r'\b|\b'.join(wordlist))` (to count individual words), the results seem to be correct. @CDJB

Answer (score 2):

This is a much faster (runtime wise) solution, if you have a very large list and a large data frame to search through.

I guess it is because it takes advantage of a dictionary (which takes O(N) to construct and O(1) to search through). Performance wise, regex search is slower.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def occurrence_counter(target_string, search_list):
    data = dict(Counter(target_string.split()))
    count = 0
    for key in search_list:
        if key in data:
            count+=data[key]
    return count

data = {'speaker':['Adam','Ben','Clair'],
        'speech': ['Thank you very much and good afternoon.',
                   'Let me clarify that because I want to make sure we have got everything right',
                   'By now you should have some good rest']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

wordlist = ['much', 'good','right']

df['speech'].apply(lambda x: occurrence_counter(x, wordlist))
```

Comment: Indeed, I agree with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'speaker': ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Clair'],
        'speech': ['Thank you very much and good afternoon.',
                   'Let me clarify that because I want to make sure we have got everything right',
                   'By now you should have some good rest']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

wordlist = ['much', 'good', 'right']

df["speech"] = df["speech"].str.split()
df = df.explode("speech")
counts = df[df.speech.isin(wordlist)].groupby("speaker").size()
print(counts)
```

Comment: Thanks! @Alex Hall. I tried your method and it also worked (a new method I never thought of)! But I am wondering 1) is it possible to "unexplode" it? I will do additional analyses using the data, so it would be nice that the dataframe remains on the speech level (one speech per row) and 2) how could I create a new column with the counts? I tried `df['counts'] = df[df.speech.isin(wordlist)].groupby("speaker").size()` and expect to have the same value for the same speaker, but the value was missing for the whole `counts' column.